# How to create a graphql query that uses the same query multiple times

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

Given query

```
query user($id: Int!) {
  getUser(id: $id) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

I'd like to grab multiple users and get them returned as an array ex: `const users = [1, 2, 3, 5]`

I it possible to query this from client, or do I need to define new Query on the server?

I am using Apollo with React btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @Jonathan's answer:

If you want to generalize to "give me an array of users based on an array of ids *and* you have the ability to add a query to the server, then define a new mutation:

```
query getUsersFromIds(ids: [ID!]!) [User]
```

Otherwise there is no generalized looping construct in GraphQL.

Comment: Thanks - I thought I maybe missed something obvious.
I can create an extra resolver, but that will mean I can't use lazy loaded fields (`resolveField` decorators). Seems that is the way to go though.

Comment: Not necessarily! If you return an array of Users you can still have individual field resolvers on the User object that behave however you want them to.

Comment: You are totally right! It worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why does this have to be a mutation vs a query?

Comment: It doesn't, not sure what I was thinking back in '22 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, this is a problem best solved by extending the schema with a `getUsers` query.

As a workaround, you can use [aliases](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) to make multiple queries within a single query.

```
query users($id1: Int!, $id2: Int!, $id3: Int!) {
  user1: getUser(id: $id1) {
    id
    name
  }
  user2: getUser(id: $id2) {
    id
    name
  }
  user3: getUser(id: $id3) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea - generating string like this would potentially work, but this would not work with Typescript, as the types are generated beforehand.